# Динамической выделение памяти с помощью malloc() в си

Tags: c, массивы, память, переполнение

Что будет, если я с помощью malloc() выделю больше оперативной памяти, чем есть у меня на компьютере?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Выделите или попытаетесь выделить? :)

Comment: Если не сумеет выделит - то вернет NULL. Но может случится, что сумеет выделить. (См. фалы подкачки, виртуальная память и т.д.)

Comment: первая половина выделенной памяти будет кэше на винчестере и вторая в реальной памяти

Comment: Зависит от операционной системы и её настроек. Если в линуксе включить максимальный overcommit, то у меня получилось «успешно выделить» 86 терабайт «памяти» (но при попытке её использовать процесс будет убит из-за нехватки настоящей памяти)

Comment: Может даже сделать вид, что выделил, а потом при реальном обращении упасть. Кажется, Саттер о таком в своих "задачах" писал.

Answer (score 0):

При вызове malloc происходит выделение виртуальной памяти, которая может быть намного больше, чем реальная RAM. То есть это зависит от операционной системы и ее настроек, и сам вызов вполне может завершиться успешно.
Беда к сожалению может прийти намного позже, при попытке использовать эту память.